# Network Connections missing in 18.04 - so how do I setup OpenDNS

Tags: networking, network-manager, dns

[This OpenDNS guide](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/228007087-Ubuntu) explains how to setup OpenDNS on older versions of Ubuntu. I'm using 18.04 *Bionic Beaver* and it appears the `Network Connections` GUI is no longer available. So I can't even accomplish step 1.

**So how do I setup OpenDNS on 18.04**, what are the proper steps mimicking [this guide](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/228007087-Ubuntu)? I assume command line could do it but that's far beyond me at this stage.

Also it appears OpenDNS offers two servers `208.67.222.222` and `208.67.220.220`. Most guides only refer to `208.67.222.222` but I'd like to use both in case one goes down.

Comment: You could look under network manager / edit connections  and add additional DNS servers under the IPV4 /IPV6 tabs.  I specified these DNS servers in my router though, not on an individual PC.

Comment: @Organic Marble How do I open Network Manager on 18.04? I think it's been deprecated. If I `network-manager` from the command line it says `command not found`. If I `sudo apt-get install network-manager` it shows it already installed. If I `Super-Key` then start typing `network manager` nothing comes up.

Comment: Unfortunately I use LXDE desktop and it's a GUI in the lower right corner of the page. I know nothing about Gnome desktop.

Comment: @Organic Marble How would I do it from the command line then?

Comment: There's a command `nmcli` that is the command line interface to network manager but I'm not very familiar with it. I just tried it with no options and it did show some DNS information.

Comment: The NetworkManager is called up by selecting "Wired Connections" or "Wi-fi Connections" from the menu in the upper-right corner or your top panel, or by opening the Settings panel, and selecting Wi-Fi or Network.